# Bootstrap Modal element Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have bootstrap Modal . and i have 3 images on it . what i want that when i click on any of this images change HTML of div.text , but its change all the div that take `.text` class i need change the html of the current div that i opened the modal . any help !!

```
<div class="Widget">
 <div class="press">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>
     <div class="text">test111</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="Widget">
 <div class="press">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>
      <div class="text">test2222</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="Widget">
 <div class="press">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>
    <div class="text">test3333</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$("#img1").click(function(){
  $(".text").html("Its woking")  
 });
```

Comment: What is `#img1` element??? Anyway, as IDs must be unique on document context, ...

Comment: Can you make a demo please, like bootply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MReEmOw3VK) with following code:

```
$("a[data-toggle='modal']").click(function(){
  $("a[data-toggle='modal']").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$("#myModal img").click(function(){
  $("a.active").next(".text").html("Its working");
});
```

When a `Modal` link is clicked, it sets the class `active` to the link that opened the modal. When an image in the modal is clicked, the `text` that should be changed can be identified as it's the text next to the active link.
The only adjustment of your markup was to add some example content inside the anchor tag - `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modal</a>` instead of `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>`, otherwise it wouldn't be possible (at least for this example) to open the modal.

Just in case - the bootply already wraps the code in a `$(document).ready()`, so the above code has to be wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// above code here
});
```

in order to work.

**Update:**  As mentioned as comment, above approach doesn't work for the original markup because there the div with the class `text` is not next to the link, but there are other divs between them.

I've adjusted this in another [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JQDJWshlYf) with following code change:

```
$("#myModal img").click(function(){
  $("a.active").closest(".Widget").find(".text").html("Its working");
});
```

When the image is clicked, `closest()` selects the closest parent of the active link and `find()` selects the child element with the class `text`.
Depending on the actual markup it's also possible to select `closest(".press")` instead of `closest(".Widget")` (both will work for this example), it's only necessary to select a parent container of the link and the `text`.

Because Bootply was sometimes down when I made these changes, I've added this also in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3czb1r7/) without bootstrap, just as example for the functionality.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: thanks buddy , its working foine in your example . but i have small problem , you use .next  because the div is the next div .. i have many div`s between the 2 dives . i using the .closest but its not working :(

Comment: @MohamedSamy I've just updated my answer with an adjustment without using `next()`, so it's now working not depending on the position of `.text` to the `.active` link.

Answer (score -1):

can not see where $('#img1') in the code your provided. But I guess what you need is $(this), something like:

```
$('.imgs').click(function(){
   $(this).html()....
});
```